# Are there any multi-type public datasets out there?

Tags: dataset

Does anyone know of any good public datasets for supervised learning that would contain data where instances are described with different types of data (ie. timeseries data, categorical data, images, ...)

The types of datasets I have in mind are:

- a dataset where each example is described with an image and some numerical features
- a dataset where each example can be described with timeseries data and some categorical features
- a dataset where each example is described with multiple images (ie. the image taken from two different angles)

An example would be a dataset of daily closing stock price data associated with news sentiment for that particular day.

I'm aware that it's possible to construct a dataset like that on my own with some scraping but I'm wondering whether there are any public datasets out there that serve this purpose.

Comment: You may have better luck on the open data stack exchange site: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php which is a great repository with tons of datasets.

Comment: Well that's pretty insulting. I correct  some link rot and am told it needs to be reviewed? Here's a working  link in the meantime https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php

Comment: @42- Thanks for updating the link